# How to solve this Reaction-Diffusion problem by FEM?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image]

I want to solve this by Finite Element Method numerically, since the exact solution is too hard.

Separation of variables does not help me here.

Epsilon is positive so cannot be Helmholtz equation.
It seems to be some sort of reaction-diffusion equation.
So here should be done more partial differential equations after the strong form has been changed into the weak for form by multiplying both sides by **v**.

I think that you can assume

$u'(1) = 0$ and $v(0) = 0$.

**How can you find the numerical value of this equation?**

Comment: Saying its a diffusion-reaction eqn is a little confusing as it is steady state. Anyway, in this case can you not use $v = u-1$ which results in $-\epsilon \Delta v + v=0$ and modify the boundary conditions then invert back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the FEniCS library!

http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/index.html 
http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/more.html
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/83776282/fenics-book-2011-10-27-final.pdf

It is freely available, and allows you to solve PDEs using finite element methods in a highly automated and easy to use manner. There is a Python interface to it (see the tutorial).